# WebAPI 2 Quartz CornSchedule not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

I am trying to schedule a task from api call to send an email. I am following their quick start guide but can't get it working.

Can anyone see what am I doing wrong?  [here's my code](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/546)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your CRON is wrong. To schedule something to run every 3 mins it should be

> 0 */3 * ? * *

Try the new cron and see whether it works as expected. If not post the console logs. Also print exception as well.

Comment: that didn't work either. Its not writing anything into console and there are no exception. I have also configure NLog on app_start but not seeing anything in log as well.

Comment: it works with "0 0/3 * ? * *" but doesn't work with "0 3 * ? * *"
they both should be technically mean the same thing

Comment: actually "0 3 * ? * *" means "At second :00 of minute :03 of every hour".